# Add sound to Notification in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, notifications

I created a notification following this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications

```
 //Create notification channel:  
` CreateNotificationChannel():
            instance.CreateNotificationChannel("enter","On_Enter");
            //Build notification
            var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(instance,"enter")
                      .SetSmallIcon(global::Android.Resource.Drawable.IcDialogInfo)
                      .SetContentTitle("Proximity") // Set the title
                      .SetContentText($"benvenuto nel beacon di colore {deskOwner}, {description}")
                      .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound)
                      .Build();
            // Get the notification manager:
            NotificationManager notificationManager = instance.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
            // Pubblico la notifica:
            const int notificationId = 0;
            notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, builder);
            return null;
        }
```

When I write SetDefaults to add the sound to the notification gives me an error: 
This is the error:
cannot convert from 'Android.App.NotificationDefaults' to 'int'.
How can i fix it?

Comment: You can try cast NotificationDefaults.Sound to int or use Notification.Builder(it's deprecated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use following line to convert it.

```
   var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                      .SetAutoCancel(true) // Dismiss the notification from the notification area when the user clicks on it
                      .SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent) // Start up this activity when the user clicks the intent.
                      .SetContentTitle("Button Clicked") // Set the title
                      .SetNumber(count) // Display the count in the Content Info
                      .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Sound)
                      .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_button_click) // This is the icon to display
                      .SetContentText($"The button has been clicked {count} times."); // the message to display.
```

But you do not need set the `SetDefaults` for notification, This method was deprecated in API level 26.use `NotificationChannel#enableVibration(boolean)` and `NotificationChannel#enableLights(boolean)` and `NotificationChannel#setSound(Uri, AudioAttributes)` instead.

You can see this thread
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setDefaults(int)